# PHP MySQLi jQuery checking database value doesn't exist

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I'm using the below PHP and jQuery script and I'm trying to check that the username put through doesn't exist in the database already.

**PHP**

```
        if(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id FROM user WHERE user_name='$username'")){
            echo '1'; //If there is a  record match in the Database - Not Available
        } else {
            echo '0'; //No Record Found - Username is available 
        }
    }
?>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("fieldset input[name=username]").change(function(){
        var username = $("fieldset input[name=username]").val();//Get the value in the username textbox
        if(username.length > 3){
            $(".username_status").html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",  
                url: "/donald/settings/check-username.php",  //file name
                data: "username="+ username,  //data
                success: function(data){
                    console.log("server_response: "+data);
                    if(data == '0'){
                        $(".username_status").html('<font color="Green"> Available </font>');
                    } else  if(data == '1'){  
                        $(".username_status").html('<font color="red">Not Available </font>');
                    }
                } 
            }); 
        } else {
            $(".username_status").html('<font color="#cc0000">Username too short</font>');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

The result always comes through as `1`

Comment: [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) see **Return Values** section. And btw you wanna bookmark php.net

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injection

Comment: @YourCommonSense please share an example of how to prevent this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) documentation:

> > > Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

So with valid query it should never return `FALSE`.
Therefore you probably want to do this, using [`mysqli_result`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php):

```
$q = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id FROM user WHERE user_name='$username'");
if( $q && $q->num_rows ){
    echo '1';
} else {
    echo '0';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

mysqli_query() returns true everytime you have a correct query, no matter its result. You need to use another mysqli_ function which will return rows i.e. mysqli_num_rows, _result or _fetch_array.

Ofcourse, each of them, has its own syntax, so you have to check it and use it properly in order to check if there's a result or not. i.e. if num_rows>0 or result($query, 0)

Answer (score 1):

You should check [mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) instead .
[mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) always return true if query is executed

Try changing php code to

```
$resource = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id FROM user WHERE user_name='$username'");
$rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($resource);  
 if($rowCount > 0){
        echo '1'; //If there is a  record match in the Database - Not Available
    } else {
        echo '0'; //No Record Found - Username is available 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id FROM user WHERE user_name='$username'"))` will allways evaluate as true, if the query went OK. THis is not what you want.